# Unparseable date Exception Windows Azure Mobile Services

Tags: java, android, sql, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am new to Windows Azure Mobile Services.  I am running a simple query on one of my tables via mobile services with the following piece of code:

```
mStudySpotTable = this.mClient.getTable(studyspot.class);
mStudySpotTable.where().field("ss_school_id").eq(1)
    .execute(new TableQueryCallback<studyspot>() {
          public void onCompleted(List<studyspot> result, 
                                  int count, 
                                  Exception exception,
                                  ServiceFilterResponse response) {
```

The studyspot class is an inner class that simply contains variables that match the columns
in the table stored in the cloud:

```
public class studyspot {
    int id;
    int ss_school_id;
    int ss_course_id;
    Date ss_startdatetime;
    Date ss_enddatetime;
    int ss_creator;
}
```

The problem I have is when I try to run my application with the query from above, I receive a com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.text.ParseException "Unparseable date:"2013-11-03T20:00:00.000Z"

I suspect the issue has something to do with the type of the ss_startdatetime and ss_enddatetime being Date objects in Java and datetime in the sql table.  Anyone out there run into this problem?

Comment: I have the same problem using the latest Azure Mobile Services SDK (2.0.1 beta). My date strings are without milliseconds though, i.e. 2013-11-03T20:00:00Z and I get "Invalid length" as the json parser error message.

Answer (score 2):

The client parser source suggests the data should be parsed as expected:

https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/sdk/android/src/sdk/src/com/microsoft/windowsazure/mobileservices/DateSerializer.java

Maybe check the Google GSON library version you're using to make sure it's compatible with the Mobile Services SDK.

Comment: This Link is Showing Page not Found :(